# Detecting if a player is using the spyglass

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am playing in the latest java snapshot (20w46a) and was trying to create costum enchantments for the spyglass; I tried using the scoreboard command, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work; is there any way to do that?